# statistics problem, where did I mistake?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory

I searched interesting problem about statistic from

http://www.mast.queensu.ca/~stat353/resources/pastfinals/final12sol.pdf
$$
$$

But at the question No.2, I have some problem **the red box**

[image]

$$
$$

Here is my opinion

$$
$$
[image]

Do I have a mistake? Could you give me some advice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you have as one event of a ball in urn 1 and a ball in urn 2 is actually two events; ball 1 in urn 1, ball 2 in urn 2, and ball 1 in urn 2, ball 2 in urn 1. Which ball goes in which urn makes a difference, according to the description of the problem.

Comment: Does my comment answer your question? or is there more to say?

Comment: Are you still there?

Comment: I'm so sorry for lating. And I'm sorry but I didn't solve yet..

Comment: And I am thinking about your comment. I truly sorry about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on my comment.

Looking at the 3 urns, 2 balls case. Let's call the balls Bert and Ernie. There are nine (not six!) equally likely cases:

Bert and Ernie both in urn 1;
Bert in 1, Ernie in 2;
Bert in 1, Ernie in 3;
Bert in 2, Ernie in 1;
Both in 2;
Bert in 2, Ernie in 3;
Bert in 3, Ernie in 1;
Bert in 3, Ernie in 2;
Both in 3.

Any given urn is empty in 4 of the 9 cases, so $$E(X_i\mid N=2)=4/9$$ for all $i$. This is not the $1/2$ you get, because the 6 cases you look at are not equally likely; the three two-balls-in-one-urn cases are only half as likely as the three balls-in-different-urns cases.

The answer I get is also not the $(n-1)/n$ from the text; what should be in the text is $$\left({n-1\over n}\right)^m$$ which agrees with what is in the next line in the text.

Comment: I am really appreciate for your kindness. In this time,I have a question,.,, the statement "N number of balls" means there are 'distinct' N balls? Thank you sincerely.

Comment: It says in the problem, "each ball is equally likely to be placed in any of the $n$ urns, independently of the placement of the other balls". This only makes sense if the balls are distinguishable.

Comment: Aha! Thank you very much.